# Atom PHP / JavaScript Reference Package

Tags: javascript, php, package, atom-editor

Exists a Atom Package that suggest functions and the expected parameters for PHP and JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for the 'atom-autocomplete-php' plugin for achieving autocompletion of tags and expected parameters in the ATOM editor.

You can install it from here [atom-autocomplete-php](https://github.com/Peekmo/atom-autocomplete-php)

And similarly for javascript you [atom-termjs](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ternjs)

HTH

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've Forgot it. Clearly. Big Thanks.